# How to automatically build org links from an org-contacts contact?

Tags: org-mode, org-link, org-contacts

Let's say I have the following contact in my `org-contacts` org file :

```
* John Doe     
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EMAIL:    john.doe@gmail.com
  :PHONE: +44 20 7630 2400
  :COMPANY: Ubuntu
  :NOTE: 
  :END:
```

How could I build a macro (I guess a function activated by a key binding) that would allow me to automatically create an `org-store-link`s that would link to an orgmode file located in `~\myfolder` based on the contact name, when I point the cursor after `:NOTE:`.

Here the generated link would be `[[~\myohterfolder\johndoe.org][John Doe Card]]`

Or maybe a function could be inserted in the `org-capture-template` to generate the link when the contact is created. Here is my template:

```
("c" "Networking Contacts" entry (file+headline "~/path/contacts.org" "Networking")
 "* %(org-contacts-template-name)
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
  :PHONE:
  :COMPANY: [[./otherpath/companies.org::][C]]
  :NOTE: 
  :END:")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `org-contacts-template-name` returns the template name ("John Doe" in your example), then you should be able to do something like this:

```
   ...
   :NOTE: [[file:~/myotherfolder/%(munge (org-contacts-template-name)).org][%(org-contacts-template-name) Card]]
   ...
```

where `munge` is a function that takes the template name and returns the basename of the file ("johndoe" in your example), e.g. by converting it to lower case and deleting whitespace:

```el
(defun munge (tname)
  (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]]+" "" tname)))
```

Tested only in simulation: I don't have `org-contacts` installed.

EDIT: here's a quick and dirty way to get the name interactively *once* and then use it later for the other cases:

```el
(defvar org-contacts-template-name nil)

(defun munge (tname)
  (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]]+" "" tname)))

(defun my-org-contacts-template-name (&optional arg)
  (if arg
      arg
    (setq org-contacts-template-name (read-from-minibuffer "Name: " nil))))

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("c" "Networking Contacts" entry (file+headline "~/tmp/org/contacts.org" "Networking")
 "* %(my-org-contacts-template-name)
  :PROPERTIES:
  :PHONE:
  :EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
  :COMPANY: [[file:~/tmp/org/companies.org::][C]]
  :NOTE: [[file:~/tmp/org/%(munge (my-org-contacts-template-name org-contacts-template-name)).org][%(my-org-contacts-template-name org-contacts-template-name) Card]]
  :END:")))
```

Basically, we define a (dynamically scoped, global) variable `org-contacts-template-name`, and we use a different function to ask the user to enter a value which is saved in that global variable. The function is called again, but now with a non-nil argument (the value of the previously-set global variable, which is just returned in that case) in the other instances of the template. This is probably quite delicate and fragile (e.g. it assumes that the capture template is processed top-to-bottom, which seems to be the case today, but there are no guarantees; there is also *no* error handling at all), but it does seem to work. Extending it to more inputs is left as an exercise. I would recommend the [Introduction to Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html): if you are going to hack Emacs Lisp, then you need to learn some :-)

Comment: Thanks for the try. Here is what it does when I do `C-c cn`: it asks me for the name, then for the email, then 2 times for the name. So in order to have the expected result, I have to type: John Doe ENTER; john.doe@gmail.com ENTER; johndoe ENTER, John Doe ENTER.

Comment: That's why I qualified it with that first "If...": I didn't (and still don't) know how `org-contacts-template-name` works: it seems that it's interactive which is a pity: you want it to be stateful in this case. I'll see what I can do, but it would be better if somebody who *actually uses* `org-contacts` could chime in.

Comment: I'm trying in vain to understand how I could code a function that would. 1. Ask me to type a value and store it as a string in a variable. So I could use the variable to populate the link (using (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]]+" "" tname))`) and the link name. So the prompt would only ask me for : name, email, card name. I only know Python, and it's quite hard for me to find how to do such simple things on Elisp.

Comment: I understand that in `org-contacts.el`, `org-contacts-template-name` only calls a function (`(or (car (org-contacts-gnus-get-name-email))`) that is pure Elisp:   (defun org-contacts-gnus-get-name-email ()
    "Get name and email address from Gnus message."
    (if (gnus-alive-p)
 (gnus-with-article-headers
   (mail-extract-address-components
    (or (mail-fetch-field "From") "")))))

Comment: That's activated only if you are using Gnus for your email and you are capturing *from* that email.  Are you? If so, then there is no interactivity. But in general, that `or` has more arguments: `(or (car (org-contacts-gnus-get-name-email))
      return-value
      "%^{Name}"))` so it returns the contact name from the email (if applicable) OR the argument to the function if non-nil OR the string `%^{Name}` which causes `org-capture` to interactively ask for a name. It's that latter case that you encountered in your first comment.

Comment: I'm not using Gnus for my emails, I'm only using gmail web client. Would you know how could I store a `read-string` input into a variable?

Comment: The same way that I used `read-from-minibuffer` in my edit to the answer: you can replace the `read-from-minibuffer` call with `read-string` if you want. See the doc strings of the two functions for the differences: `C-h f read-from-minibuffer` etc.

Comment: When I test your solution, I'm asked twice for the `Name`.  In my response/solution it is also the case because I didn't manage to simply pass a variable. Also, I've done the exercise you mentioned, namely with the `Company` input.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and for your precious help. This introduction looks pretty long though. I've learned Python with SoloLearn, but I'm afraid learning through gamification is not possible with Emacs.

Comment: DId you change all the `org-contacts-template-name` calls to `my-org-contacts-template-name`? You should only get one question for the name. As for the intro, it's not as long as the Emacs Lisp manual (and you'll have to read some of that eventually). There is indeed no royal road to Emacs Lisp...

Comment: No I didn't change `org-contacts.el` nor `org-contacts-template-name`. I just copy-pasted your code and changed the paths. I think it's logical that it is asked twice since the input function is called twice. That's why I put an output function in my code (see the edit of my answer), which works quite well now.

Comment: The input function is called *three* times, but it only asks for input the first time. The other two times, it is passed a non-nil argument and is happy with returning that.

Comment: After `NOTE:` `my-org-contacts-template-name` is called 2 times as `org-contacts-template-name` is. I had the same problem when I put `con-input` twice after `NOTE:` (once for the link path and once for the link name). That's why I'm using `princ` for the link name, so the input is only asked once.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are misunderstanding the situation but I don't have time to argue with you.

Comment: I'm just trying to explain what I'm understanding, which I agree is quite limited. Probably I'm wrong in my understanding, but I sure got 2 input prompts for name with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NickD inputs I found a satisfying solution. Here is the code:

##### Naming Org file

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun org-name (tname)
    (downcase (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]]+" "" tname)))
#+end_src
```

##### Contact name input

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun con-input()
    (setq x (read-from-minibuffer "Card : ")))
#+end_src
```

##### Company name input

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun com-input()
    (setq y (read-from-minibuffer "Company : ")))
#+end_src
```

##### org-contacs capture

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
  ("c" "Networking Contacts" entry (file+headline "...path/contacts.org" "Networking")
   "* %(org-contacts-template-name)
:PROPERTIES:
:EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
:PHONE:
:NOTE:  [[.../otherpath/%(org-name(con-input)).org][%(princ x) Card]]
:COMPANY: [[.../anotherpath/companies.org::%(com-input)][%(princ y)]]
:NOTE: 
:END:")
#+end_src
```

Comment: The output functions are unnecessary and confusing: you don't care about printing anything to an output stream. `princ` happens to *return* its argument (which is what you use here), but it is principally used to print something to an output stream (which you don't use here at all - that's why I think it's confusing). You also should not call the canned `org-contacts-template-name` since it will ask a question: the object of the game (I thought) was to ask as few questions as possible and then fill in the blanks with the answer or a somewhat massaged version of the answer.

Comment: The goal (sorry if it wasn't clear enough in my question) was to automatically build an org-link from the org-contacts prompt. I thought at first it would be a good idea to use the package name function. But afterward, thought it would be easier not to.

Comment: The code I wrote is providing me with the expected results. I don't really understand why `princ` is wrong, but if you have an alternative that would produce the same results, I'd be happy to edit my code with it.